# Graphical Front-end for Python script

Tags: python

I wrote a python script here [Github](https://github.com/harbhag/Python-Scripts/blob/master/backup_script.py)

It is just something I wrote to practice.  The script asks for a input directory and output directory and the method of compression and then compress the files from input directory and stores the compressed archive to the output directory.

I want to make a graphical frontend for this script. I am using Ubuntu 10.10 (GNOME). 
Is it possible to do so?
If yes, then where should I start?

I want to do this just for learning purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's certainly possible.  There are a ton of GUI frameworks available so you'll have more then enough choices.  Given your OS is Ubuntu I would look into [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) first.  I personally found PyGTK fit my brain pretty well and I really liked the documentation.  The fact that it's the native toolkit for your Window Manager is a nice plus in that your app will hopefully look like the other Gnome apps you're already running.

Of course you could use [Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) which is bundled with Python and cross platform.  Or you could look into using [PyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) or [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/).

To be a little crazy, since this is a learning exercise, you might want to use something lower level so you might look into something like [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/documentation.html) or [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) and spend some time learning how to build your UI widgets.

If you're looking for touch interface or iOS / Android support then checkout [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home)

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for showing several alternatives witnout getting preachy

Comment: +1 for suggesting Pyglet and Pygame!Never thought of them as GUI options

Comment: Thanks, I think I will try PyGTK first.

Answer (score 2):

[Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) also looks like a good alternative.

`Kivy - Open source Python library for rapid development of applications
that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps.`

Answer (score 1):

I found `PyQt` pretty easy to get up and running with. Check out the wiki docs [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro).

Answer (score -2):

I find [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) a very good design pattern to use in this case, so, you might try to salvage your code (it seems very simple).

For a GUI framework, I suggest Mike Steder's response, and this list and a large list found [here.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)

Comment: -1 MVC has no relevance to the post and it's hard to imagine it has any application to the code.

Comment: MVC allows you to write one model, and have multiple front ends. MVC is not always just for webapps.